Tabulator6.2 Money Formatter consider thousands separator as decimal
i got data in a google spreadsheet like
1   toto    Ruta Salares    7/1/2024    07:00   TRUE    46.000  RAFA 
2   titi    Ruta Salares    7/1/2024    07:00   TRUE    46.000  RAFA
3   zoe Geysers 7/1/2024    04:30   TRUE    40.000  Nico 
4   zut Geysers 7/1/2024    04:30   TRUE    40.000  Nico 

when tabulator 6.2 column definition is
{title: "Precio de Venta", field: "value", formatter:"money", formatterParams:{
    decimal:",", thousand:".", symbol:"CLP", precision:0,}, validator:[ "numeric", "required"], topCalc:"sum", topCalcParams:{
    decimal:",", thousand:".", symbol:"CLP", precision:0,}, hozAlign:"right"},

it converts the values to 46,46,40,40
i changed the definition of the column,  forced the "numeric" format in the google sheet.
when i echo the data sent, i see effectively 46.000,00 , 46.000,00 , 40.000,00
but tabulator shows 46 46 40 40... i am a bit troubled... having to modify each data before sending it to the tabulator or using a mutator could be an option but i first wanted to document this behaviour as i am sure i am not the only one...
